# Add an input text who have the size of a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem perhaps has a simple answer but I don't know of it.

I have a select box which adapts its size to its possible values but I can't get it's size by something like `$('#idSlect').attr('size')` because it doesn't have a size attribute, it just adapts itself.

How can I make my input text the same size as my select box?

What I want is something like:

```
$('#idInputText').size($('#idSelect').size())
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: can we see the code of how the select resizes itself?

Comment: [jQuery .width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/), [jQuery .height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) maybe?

Comment: I realised you're not English, but it looks like you typed out this question while drunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about inspecting the width of the select and setting the width of the input to the same value;

```
var w = $("#idSlect").css("width");

$("#idInputText").css("width", w);
```

Comment: Why not use `.width()`?

Comment: you could, but: The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

Comment: @DubstepCat Here's a little speedtest I just knocked together. Apparently the quickest (and therefore probably the best) method is not the one you would expect! http://jsfiddle.net/ce511sds/2/

Comment: that is interesting. although the difference is marginal I would not have expected calling a parse function to be quicker!

Answer (score 1):

A simple function to grab the height and width of an element and apply it to another:

```
function MatchSize(OriginalElement, TargetElement) {
    // Grab the original element height and width
    var CurrentWidth = OriginalElement.width();
    var CurrentHeight = OriginalElement.height();

    // Assign the height and width to the target element
    TargetElement.width(CurrentWidth);
    TargetElement.height(CurrentHeight);
}
```

Then just supply the elements in the function call:

```
MatchSize($('select'), $('input'));
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/db2ga57b/)

Answer (score 0):

The way to catch an element width with jQuery is like so:

```
$('selector').css('width')
```

And you can make the input the same size like so:

```
$('#input').css('width', $('#select').css('width'))
```

But the best way to do this is using CSS for a more uniform design of your page

```
<style>
    #input, #select{
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: he says the width is responsive so you couldn't hardcode the width in the css.